# Can Gradle handle a build directory structure that does not conform default conventions?

Tags: java, maven, ant, ivy, gradle

I am working on a [java](/questions/tagged/java) [ant](/questions/tagged/ant)+[ivy](/questions/tagged/ivy) based project that has the following directory structure:

```
projectRoot/src
projectRoot/classes
projectRoot/conf
projectRoot/webservices
```

this works perfectly well in [ant](/questions/tagged/ant) but I am looking to migrate to [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle).

Is there a way to define a non-maven directory structure in Gradle or should I be looking to [mavenize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3372955/411902)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is very easy with Gradle to adapt to any directory structure. See the [Working with source sets](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#source_sets) section of the Gradle User Guide.

Answer (score 14):

Example with non-standard project directory structure (custom layout):

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'sources/main/java'
        }
        outputDir = file("$workDir/client/program")
        // For older version (now deprecated):
        //output.classesDir = "$workDir/client/program"
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'sources/test/java'
        }
        outputDir = file("$workDir/client/tests")
        // For older versions (now deprecated):
        //output.classesDir = "$workDir/client/tests"
        //output.resourcesDir = "$workDir/client/tests"
    }
    resources {
        srcDirs 'sources/test/res'
    }
}
```

Comment: After hours of searching today, this solved my problem.
For some reason the --project-root argument and rootProject.projectDir are ignored? No matter what I do "println project.projectDir" within build.gradle always echos the folder in which build.gradle lives in.

Using: srcDir '../../src/main/java" fixed the problem.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/java'
    main.resources.srcDirs += 'src/resources'
}
```