# What is the verb form of maven?

Tags: maven

I have some Java projects that do not have a good build process. I plan on introducing Maven, and possibly ant, to these projects to rectify the lack of a build process. When I tell people on my team that I'm mavenizing a project, I get a weird stare. I think there should be a verb form of Maven, rather than having to say "I'm going to reconfigure this project to use Maven as a build tool" I could just say "I'm going to mavenize this project"

Some possible verbs I've come up with follow. Please forgive the mixed tense.

Mavenize - "I'm going to mavenize this project"
Mavenate - "I'm going to mavenate this project"
Mave - "I'm going to mave this project"
Maven - "I'm going to maven this project"
Mavenify - "I'm going to mavenify this project"
Mavenerate - "I'm going to mavenerate this project"

Is there any consensus or community uptake on these semantics?

Comment: I've heard "mavenize" before, but I have no idea if this is a consensus word used by other people. Why do you care if you get a weird stare? As long as they understand you, there's no problem.

Comment: While I'm generally a fan of verbing words without changing them at all, I like mavenate.

Comment: I already "saw" Mavenize :) that would be my choice

Comment: Mavenize sounds the most official of the lot, it just seems to lack some of the pizazz of mavenate.

Comment: You could probably google each and see what gets you the most hits.

Comment: I've always used "Mavenize" but you forgot "Mavenify".

Comment: @codethulhu I've added mavenify- good call

Comment: @StephenTG I like this xkcd metric approach. The only two of those I've listed that are distinctly for Apache Maven are "mavenize" and "maven".

Comment: @Jesper I generally care about weird stares because too many of them means my ideas probably wont be taken seriously. Not everyone understands its meaning, too. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372955/what-does-it-mean-to-mavenize-a-project

Comment: "Mavenize" -> 18,500 results , "Mavenate" -> 73 results, "Mavenify" -> 73 results,

Comment: @StephenTG Google? How does one join this "Google"

Comment: Since you're putting the project into Maven form, maybe it could be "enmavening" ?

Comment: I've used Mavenize as well. Also consider 'Gradling it'. Depending on how complex your build is, that may be a better solution. http://gradle.org

Comment: @araqnid Good point. "Mavening a project" could mean building it with maven. enmavening implies adding maven more. ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mavenize` is the form I always use... but I am only a Maven committer and on the project management committee, so what would I know